# What does $(a_n)_n \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, natural-numbers

What does $(a_n)_n \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ mean?

What kind of sequence is that? How does the indexing work?

What's the $A$ to natural numbers power?

Comment: It is a sequence indexed by the naturals with elements in $A$. That's what it means.

Comment: Another way to formulate this is: $$(a_n)_n\in A^\mathbb{N} \iff \forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ } a_n\in A$$

Comment: @Yanko The double $_n$ index confuses me in $(a_n)_n$. It looks like subsequences.

Comment: Yeah I don't love the double index either, but it is common notation. It reads: "the set of elements named $a_n$, indexed over the changing parameter $n$."

Comment: @mavavilj I see. A more formal way would be to write $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (Just like $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ but a sequence is not a set, the order matters). In other words $(a_n)_n = (a_1,a_2,a_3,...)$.

Answer (score 4):

That power notation indicates the set of functions, $A^\mathbb{N} = \{f: \mathbb{N} \to A\}$, which in this case means the set of infinite sequences of elements of $A$.

Comment: Important example: If $A=\mathbb{R}$ then $A^\mathbb{N}$ is simply the set of all real sequences (the usual sequences you learn about in a standard calculus course).

Comment: Where does it say that it contains sequences, I see functions?

Comment: A function from the natural numbers is exactly the same data as a sequence. $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$ corresponds to the sequence $f(1), f(2), f(3), ...$

Comment: @NathanielMayer So essentially they are just "labeled" elements of $A$?

Comment: Yeah. What is a sequence of elements of $A$? It's a choice of first element $a_1$, then second element $a_2$, and so on. That's exactly equivalent to a function $1 \mapsto a_1$, $2 \mapsto a_2$, etc.